# Show that $C^*\colon G\to C^*(G)$ is a functor from $Gr$ to Cstar

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, category-theory, c-star-algebras, functors

> Let $Gr$ denote the category of discrete groups where the morphisms are group homomorphisms, and let Cstar denote the category of $C^∗$-algebras where the morphisms are $∗$-homomorphisms. Show that $C^*\colon G\to C^*(G)$ is a functor from $Gr$ to $C^*$. In other words, show that any group homomorphism $\psi\colon G\to H$ induces a $∗$-homomorphism $C^*(\psi) \colon C^*(G)\to C^*(H)$ in a natural way such that:
>
> 1. $C^*(id_G) = id_{C^* }(G)$,
> 2. If $\psi\colon G\to H$ and $\varphi:H\to K$ are group homomorphisms, then $C^∗(\varphi\circ \psi) =C^∗(\varphi)\circ C^∗(\psi).$

I'm not sure if this question has asked before or not but  I have done this, is this the correct way to show functor? If not, what is the other way.

1. $C^∗$ preserves identities:

For any group $G$, the identity morphism $id_G: G \to G$ is a group homomorphism. We know, $C^∗(G)$ is the $C^*$-algebra associated with the group $G$. The identity morphism $id_G\colon G \to G$ induces a -homomorphism $C^∗(id_G)\colon C^∗(G) \to C^∗(G)$ by mapping group elements to the corresponding elements in the $C$-algebra.

This $*$-homomorphism $C^∗(id_G)$ is defined as the identity map on the elements of $C^∗(G)$. In other words, for any element $a$ in $C^∗(G)$, we have $C^∗(id_G)(a) = a$.

Hence, $C^∗(id_G) = id_(C^∗(G))$, and the identity preservation condition is satisfied.

2. $^∗$ preserves composition:

Consider two group homomorphisms $\psi\colon G \to H$ and $\varphi \colon H \to K$.
Let $a$ be an element in $C^∗(G)$. Then $C^∗(\psi\circ\varphi)(a)$ is the image of $a$ under the $*$-homomorphism $C^∗(\psi\circ\varphi)\colon C^∗(G) \circ C^∗(K)$.

$C^∗(\psi\circ\varphi)(a)$ can be computed by first applying $C^∗(\psi)$ to $a$, which maps $a$ to an element $b$ in $C^∗(H)$, and then applying $C^∗(\varphi)$ to $b$, which maps $b$ to an element $c$ in $C^∗(K)$.

We have $$C^∗(\psi\circ\varphi)(a)= C^∗(\varphi)(C^∗(\psi)(a))= C^∗(\varphi)\circ ^∗(\psi)(a).$$

Therefore, $C^∗$ preserves composition.

Comment: What you should be focusing on here is the following: does a group homomorphism induce a $*$-morphism between the corresponding group $C^*$-algebras? Your answer does not say anything about this!

Comment: Use `$\to$` for $\to$ and `$\circ$` for $\circ$. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: [You have been told about solution verification questions before.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703711/consider-inductive-sequence-of-c-ast-algebra-a-1-overset%cf%86-1%e2%86%92a-2-overset%cf%86#comment9956521_4703711)

Comment: This would be a fine post, just, it needs focus on why you think there is a problem. I was initially confused as to why there where downvotes